# android change swipe sensitivity for HorizontalPager in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have implemented an image slider with HorizontalPager in compose.
Now it is required to swipe more than 50% of the screen-width to get to the next/prev image and it is a very long swipe.
how can I reduce that to 25%?
thanks for your answers.